# I put the zoom to get my mobile screen focused to 5 km from my current location

Tags: android, maps

I am creating an android app where I am displaying current location. I just want to know what should I put the zoom to get my mobile screen focused to 5 km from my current location. Thank You in advance.

Comment: So do you want your current position in the center of the map and display an area with a 5km radius?

Comment: Yes. Please tell the zoom value that would do that

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the width of your map view element.

According to [CameraPosition.Builder.zoom](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.Builder.html#zoom(float)):

> Sets the zoom level of the camera. Zoom level is defined such that at
>   zoom level 0, the whole world is approximately 256dp wide (assuming
>   that the camera is not tilted). Increasing the zoom level by 1 doubles
>   the width of the world on the screen. Hence at zoom level N, the width
>   of the world is approximately 256 * 2 N dp, i.e., at zoom level 2, the
>   whole world is approximately 1024dp wide.
>
> When changing the camera position for a map, the zoom level of the
>   camera is restricted to a certain range depending on various factors
>   including location, map type and map size. Use
>   GoogleMap.getMinZoomLevel and GoogleMap.getMaxZoomLevel to find the
>   restrictions. Note that the camera zoom need not be an integer value.

You could try something like this:

```
private int calculateZoomLevel(int mapViewWidthInDp)
{
double equatorLength = 40075004; // in meters
double widthInDp = mapViewWidthInDp;
double metersPerDp = equatorLength / 256;
int zoomLevel = 0;
while ((metersPerDp * widthInDp) > 10000) {
        metersPerDp /= 2;
        ++zoomLevel;
    }
return zoomLevel;
}
```